# Studying Chapter 10 of Weibel's Introduction to Homological Algebra

Tags: homological-algebra, mirror-symmetry

In Weibel's text on Homological Algebra, Chapter 10 deals with the Derived Category. Is it necessary to study all 9 chapters before it to make Chapter 10 accessible? (Assuming a background of Groups, Rings, Modules and Galois Theory at the level of Dummit at Foote).

I should mention that my goal is to gather background to study problems in Mirror Symmetry if that helps in any way.